# How to show git diff in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a build job in Jenkins, which is based on a git project.
Looking at the changes page for each build, I can see the commits that are new to this version, who contributed them, and the list of files modified.

What I'm missing is the option to see the actual diff - what lines of code were changed.
How can this be achieved?

I'm using a local git repo hosted on the same PC as the jenkins server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Last Changes Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Last+Changes+Plugin) to accomplish that.

Just install it and make sure to choose from `Post-build Actions` drop down menu the option `Publish Last Changes`.